# Decrypt PEM containing key and certificate

Tags: encryption, ssl, certificate, openssl

I have a .pem file which contains both my certificate and encrypted private key, ie:

```
Bag Attributes
....
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes
....
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
....
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And I need to instead have a .pem file containing both the certificate and the decrypted private key. How can I achieve this on linux, preferrably utilising the openssl application?

Answer (score 14):

To decrypt a private key from a pem file you would do something like this with a subcommand (rsa, pkey, pkcs8, pkcs12):

```
openssl rsa -in inputfilename -out outputfilename
```

Your input file is different because you concatenated both keys in one file. But you can simple edit the pem file to split it in 2 files.

Comment: I think you need a subcommand in there. Maybe `pkey`? Please @ me when you fix it and I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: Yes, it should be `pkey` for new format keys (PKCS8) or `rsa` for the older PKCS1.

Comment: Added suggestion of @Spiff

Comment: To do it without editing: `openssl x509 <in >out; openssl pkey <in >>out`

Comment: Hi All, is there any updated answer for this? I have the same issue. These commands did not work for me